# I don't know From path is correct or not while create jar file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jar

I need to create a jar file from my old project, but i don't know which path is correct.

This is my code for create jar:

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'libs/jars/logmanagementlib.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/app_classes/release') // app_classes folder is not there
    into('libs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'logmanagementlib.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

This is my available folders names:

**\app\build\intermediates**

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI11D.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcqw9.png)